# Renaming a folder, and merging with exisiting folder if it exists in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-3.0

Trying to do some directory cleanups, and transition from an old methodology to a new one. Currently we've been doing it manually, case-by-case, but I decided to look into [automating the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63715596/create-folders-from-csv-txt-and-move-matching-column-into-new-directory-in-power/63716032#63716032).

This worked in theory until we started extracting more CSV data, and ran into new issues.

What I cannot find an answer for anywhere is "renaming a folder, and if the name exists then merge the two" exactly like you would see in Windows Explorer:

[image]

I know this is dangerous - but its the only way I can think of it.

I [looked into](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32728393/1086990) `Copy-Item` but since the folders range from a few MB all the way to `>20GB` (and on average at the larger side). It's too slow to copy, move child items, then delete - plus with about 8000 folders to create and move I don't think there's enough buffer storage.

Is it possible to merge the folders, and sub folders into the newly created one?

This is what I have so far:

```bsh
# set the working directory
Set-Location "B:\"

# import the CSV file for folder creation
$folders = Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Header @("ID","caseName","caseNumber") -Path .\export.csv

# begin the loop
ForEach( $folder in $folders ) {

   # create the variables
   $columnID = $folder.ID
   $columnCase = "{0} {1}" -f $folder.caseName, $folder.caseNumber
   $columnNewCase = "{1}, {0}" -f $folder.caseName, $folder.caseNumber

   # use later to create root folders
   $yearAllocation = "20{0}" -f $folder.caseNumber.Substring(0,2)


   #
   # // MARK: begin main folder creation
   #

   # "SMITH 12345678" and "12345678, SMITH" do NOT exist
   if( (-not ( Test-Path "$columnCase" )) -and (-not ( Test-Path "$columnNewCase" )) ) {
       # create the "12345678, SMITH"
       New-Item "$columnNewCase" -ItemType Directory
   }

   # "SMITH 12345678" EXISTS but "12345678, SMITH" does NOT exist
   if( ( Test-Path "$columnCase" ) -and (-not ( Test-Path "$columnNewCase" )) ) {
       # rename "SMITH 12345678" -> "12345678, SMITH"
       Rename-Item "$columnCase" -NewName $columnNewCase -Force
   }

   # "SMITH 12345678" does NOT exist but "12345678, SMITH" EXISTS
#   if( (-not ( Test-Path "$columnCase" )) -and ( Test-Path "$columnNewCase" ) ) {
#      # do nothing
#   }

   # "SMITH 12345678" and "12346578, SMITH" both EXIST
   if( ( Test-Path "$columnCase" ) -and ( Test-Path "$columnNewCase" ) ) {
       # merge "SMITH 12345678" -> "12345678, SMITH"
   }


   #
   # // MARK: begin ID folder moves
   #

   # if "98765" folder exists
   if( Test-Path "$columnID" ) {
       # move "98765" into "12345678, SMITH"
       Move-Item "$columnID" -Destination "$columnNewCase"
   }
}
```

In the end I'd hope that we could get something that looks like this currently:

```
B:\
- 12345
- 23445
- 63574
- 73363
- SMITH 12345678
- JONES 58478945
```

into:

```
B:\
- 12345678, SMITH
--- 12345
--- 23445
- 58478945, JONES
--- 63574
--- 73363
```

and if someone accidentally created a new manual folder:

```
B:\
- 12345678, SMITH
--- 12345
--- 23445
- 58478945, JONES
--- 63574
--- 73363
- SMITH 12345678
--- 66684
```

then re-running the script would simply:

```
B:\
- 12345678, SMITH
--- 12345
--- 23445
--- 66684
- 58478945, JONES
--- 63574
--- 73363
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is the difference between "merging" and "copying". For me its the same, if you copy something, it ll overwrite same files (source and destination) leaving others aside, isnt merging doing the same?

Comment: Adis is correct.  When you copy in powershell it will merge folders with the same name by default.  You can just `copy-item` to merge, then `remove-item` for the files copied over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there isn't a way to merge folders in Powershell.

I ended up solving the problem by scanning all the subfolders in the original folder and moving them into the new destination.

As a precaution then move the original folder into another destination so we could do a file size property check if anything was missed.

```bsh
# set the working directory
Set-Location "C:\"

# import the CSV file for folder creation
# create the headers for the file since CSVs dont have them
$csvRows = Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Header @("ID","name","number") -Path .\file.csv

# begin the loop
    ForEach( $csvRow in $csvRows ) {

    # create the variables
    $columnID = $csvRow.ID
    $columnNameNumber = "{0} {1}"  -f $csvRow.name, $csvRow.number
    $columnNumberName = "{1}, {0}" -f $csvRow.name, $csvRow.number


    #
    # // MARK: begin main folder creation
    #

    # "SMITH 12345678" and "13246578, SMITH" do NOT exist
    if( (-not ( Test-Path "$columnNameNumber" )) -and (-not ( Test-Path "$columnNumberName" )) ) {
        # create the "12345678, SMITH"
        New-Item "$columnNumberName" -ItemType Directory
    }

    # "SMITH 12345678" EXISTS but "13246578, SMITH" does NOT exist
    if( ( Test-Path "$columnNameNumber" ) -and (-not ( Test-Path "$columnNumberName" )) ) {
        # rename "SMITH 12345678" -> "12345678, SMITH"
        Rename-Item "$columnNameNumber" -NewName $columnNumberName -Force
    }

    # "SMITH 12345678" does NOT exist but "13246578, SMITH" EXISTS
    if( (-not ( Test-Path "$columnNameNumber" )) -and ( Test-Path "$columnNumberName" ) ) {
        # do nothing
    }

    # "SMITH 12345678" and "13246578, SMITH" both EXIST
    if( ( Test-Path "$columnNameNumber" ) -and ( Test-Path "$columnNumberName" ) ) {
        # find all the items in $columnNameNumber
        $subDirectory = Get-ChildItem $columnNameNumber -Name

        # loop through and move to $columnNameNumberNew
        ForEach( $childItem in $subDirectory ) {
            Move-Item "$columnNameNumber\$childItem" -Destination "$columnNumberName"
        }

        # rename to know its done
        if( ( Test-Path .\destination ) ) {
            Move-Item "$columnNameNumber" -Destination .\destination
        }
    }


    #
    # // MARK: begin ID folder moves
    #

    # if "98765" folder exists
    if( Test-Path "$columnID" ) {
        # move "98765" into "12345678, SMITH"
        Move-Item "$columnID" -Destination "$columnNumberName"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!